# onhover open a popup but it close only when i click on rest of the page or close button

Tags: jquery

onhover open a popup but it close only when i click on rest of the page or close button

```
$('#promo').mouseover(function() {

        $('#promoarrow').show();

    });

    $('#closebtn').click(function() {

        $('#promoarrow').hide();

    });
```

here is the fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/YFY5g/16/

Comment: i want to click on rest of the page and #promoarrowv should get close bt if i click on #promoarrow its getting close

Comment: i want to close poppup only on click of close button and rest of the body not on click by #promoarrow

Comment: @SACHIN Hide the `promoarrow` in `$(document).click()` also

Comment: @SACHIN Now after your second comment, I am not very sure what you want..

Comment: i tried can u please help me out by exact code @Canmah

Comment: see i am hovering on #promo and #promoarrow is getting open.now clicking on close button its getting close.now i want to close this button when i click on rest of the page. but if i click on #promoarrow div its shouldnt be close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this??

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target)
        target = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement)
        target = e.srcElement;
    else
        target = e.currentTarget;

    if (target.id != 'promoarrow') $('#promoarrow').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: yes bt sort of but if i am clicking on #promoarrow its getting close as well.I dont want that how to prevent

Comment: @SACHIN Try now, If you are using lightbox then bind this even to the overlay div.

Comment: @Canmah please help me out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23449/discussion-between-sachin-and-)

Comment: @SACHIN I can't reproduce the problem, Its working perfectly in IE7 & IE8. Not working in IE6, it doesn't even open the fiddle properly.